# Apache Spark on a cloud Infrastructure

Tags: apache-spark, cloud, iaas

How can I process the given data efficiently using Apache Spark on a cloud Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) platform? I have a dataset of over 60 million data that I need to run the dataset effectively.

Comment: You don't need Spark. Have you tried using a database?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to do the same.
In Azure you can use Synapse/Azure Data Factory.
In GCS,you can use Dataproc cluster with Cloud Composer.It would be great if you can mention the whole scenario what is your exact source(csv/RDBMS table/IOT) and what would be the target/sink then it would be easier to provide answer